# 2 divs on one line with form in between

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to get one div to float left, and one div to float right, but have a form in between, the form has 2 select elements(drop down boxes) in it.

I can get it so I have:

Div<------------->Text<------------->Div

but not

Div<------------->Form<------------->Div

If I just have an empty form element than it works like the text, but as soon as I put the 2 selects in then the right div drops down a line, the same happens if I put a textbox(input, type text) in place of the 2 selects.

This is the code I have so far (Note I'm not using stylesheet for the moment, but I will eventually)

```
<div class="nav" style="text-align:center;">

<div class="prev" style="float:left;"><a href="/index.php?m=7" rel="nofollow">« July</a></div>

<form method="get" action="" id="form1">

<select id="months" name="month" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8" selected="selected">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select id="year" name="yr" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010" selected="selected">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>

</form>

<div style="float:right;" class="next"><a href="/index.php?m=9" rel="nofollow">September »</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to ditch the floating, as none of the answers really worked (don't want to set widths, jdc0589's answers didn't float the divs left and right, and when I did it broke, and floating the form left obviously made it not in the center) so I had to use absolute positioning:

```
<div class="nav" style="text-align:center;  position:relative;">

<div style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; min-width:105px;" class="prev"><a href="/index.php?m=7" rel="nofollow">« July</a></div>

<form method="get" action=""  id="form1">

<select style="" id="months" name="month" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8" selected="selected">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select style="" id="year" name="yr" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit();">
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010" selected="selected">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>

</form>

<div style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;  min-width:105px;" class="next"><a href="/index.php?m=9" rel="nofollow">July »</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The HTML `<form>` element is by default a [**block** element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) like as `<div>` is. It will always go in its own new line. You need to either `display` it `inline` or to `float` it to `left` as well. Since the two other div's are already floated, easiest is to just float the form as well. E.g.

```
<form style="float: left;">
```

That said, consider placing CSS style in its own CSS file and reference by ID's and classes.

Comment: floating is great, but often abused. This is an OK time to be using it, but there are better solutions (inline-block)

Comment: Yes I will put the CSS style in it's own CSS file, just putting it in the HTML file until I get it sorted. Surely floating the form left will make it not in the center?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to do this. Css "display: inline-block" is the easiest thing to use. Contrary to popular belief, it DOES have perfect crossbrowser support if the correct tricks are used. Here is an example: (zoom and *display are to make IE play nice)

```
<html>
  <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .element
            {
                 display:inline-block;
                 zoom:1;
                *display:inline;
            }
        </style>
  </head>

    <body>
        <div class="element">
            Stuff in here....
        </div>
        <form class="element">
                <input type="text" name="testInput" />
        </form>
        <div class="element">
                More stuff
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried,t his and it worked great in Firefox and chrome (as usual), even when I added float:right to the div which says more stuff. But in opera it works good until I add the float:right to the more stuff div, and then the div jumps down a line?

Comment: You should not have to use float at all with this method. If you need another element displayed the same way, just slap the "element" class on it. If it still jumps down a line it's simply because there wasnt enough space to fit it on the previous line (element was wider than what was available)

Comment: But what you gave was: `<----->DivFormDiv<----->` whereas I wanted `Div<----->Form<----->Div`

Comment: Not following your notation, but you can have inline block elements inside of a wrapping div if thats what you are after

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have not assigned width property for divs and forms. If you have floated 2 divs, form should also be floated.

```
<div class="nav" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="prev" style="float:left;width:200px; background-color:#454545"><a href="/index.php?m=7" rel="nofollow">« July</a></div>

<form method="get" action="" id="form1" style="width:200px; background-color:#454545; float:left">

</form>

<div style="float:right;width:200px; background-color:#454545" class="next"><a href="/index.php?m=9" rel="nofollow">September »</a></div>

</div>
```

The width is random given. Use [this tool](http://www.pagecolumn.com/3_column_div_generator_m.htm) to decide the width value

Comment: But the text in the anchors in the divs are dynamic, and I don't see why I should have to specify widths, it makes it less flexible.